# Complexity of recognizing vertex-transitive graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, gr.group-theory

I am not knowledgeable in the area of complexity theory involving groups so I apologize if this is a well known result.

> **Question 1.** Let $G$ be a simple undirected graph of order $n$. What is the
>   computational complexity (in terms of $n$) of determining if $G$ is
>   vertex-transitive?

Recall that a graph $G$ is *vertex-transitive* if $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ acts transitively on $V(G).$

I am not sure if the above definition allows for a polynomial time algorithm since it can be that the order of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is exponential.

However vertex-transitive graphs have some other structural properties that might be exploited in order to be able to efficiently determine them so I am not sure what is the status of the above question.

Another interesting subclass of vertex-transitive graphs that has even more structure is the class of [Cayley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) graphs. So it is natural to also pose the following related question

> **Question 2.** What is the computational complexity of determing if a graph $G$ is a
>   Cayley graph?

Comment: Even though the automorphism group can be super-exponential, I think it can be represented in polynomial space because the minimum number of generators is at most logarithmic in $|\textrm{Aut}(G)|$

Comment: Note that every vertex-transitive graph is a Cayley-Schrier graph: there is some group $G$ with generating set $S$ and subgroup $H$ such that the vertices of the graph are the cosets $G/H$, and two cosets are linked by an edge if some element of $S$ takes one to the other.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156947/vertex-transitive-and-cayley-graphs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but I think both problems are open.

---

The paper by Jajcay, Malnič, Marušič [3] is related to your first question.
They provide some tools to test vertex-transitivity. They say in the introduction that:

> For a given finite graph $\Gamma$,
>   it is decidedly hard to determine whether $\Gamma$ is vertex-transitive,
>   and the ultimate answer comes usually only after a substantial part of
>   the full automorphism group of $\Gamma$ has been determined.

Note that vertex-transitivity test can be done by testing graph isomorphism $n−1$ times.
Make two copies $G$ and $G'$ of your graph,
with special anchors (like paths of length $n+1$) at $u \in V(G)$ and $v \in V(G')$.
There is an isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ if and only if
the original graph has an automorphism mapping $u$ to $v$.
Thus you can test vertex-tansitivity by fixing a vertex $x$,
and checking that there are automorphisms mapping $x$ to all the other vertices.

Also note that if vertex-transitivity test can be done in polynomial time,
then so is isomorphism test for vertex-transitive graphs.
This is because two vertex-transitive graphs are isomorphic if and only if
their disjoint union is vertex-transitive.
I believe that complexity of graph isomorphism for vertex-transitive graphs is not known.

---

For the 2nd question, I found a partial result.
A *circulant graph* is a Cayley graph on a cyclic group.
Evdokimov and Ponomarenko [2] show that recognition of
circulant graphs can be done in polynomial time.
Also the book chapter by Alspach [1, Chapter 6: Cayley graphs, Section 6.2: Recognition]
would be interesting for you, although it says that:

> We shall ignore the computational problem of recognizing whether an
>   arbitrary graph is a Cayley graph. Instead, we always assume that
>   Cayley graphs have been described in terms of the groups on which they
>   are built, together with the connection sets. For most problems this
>   is not a drawback.

---

1. Beineke, Wilson, Cameron. [Topics in Algebraic Graph Theory](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=z2K26gZLC1MC&pg=PA156). Cambridge University Press, 2004.
2. Evdokimov, Ponomarenko. Circulant graphs: Recognizing and isomorphism testing in polynomial time. St. Petersburg Math. J. 15 (2004) 813-835. [doi:10.1090/S1061-0022-04-00833-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S1061-0022-04-00833-7)
3. Jajcay, Malnič, Marušič. On the number of closed walks in vertex-transitive graphs. Discrete Math. 307 (2007) 484-493. [doi:10.1016/j.disc.2005.09.039](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2005.09.039)

Comment: In fact, vertex-transitivity can be tested using $n-1$ graph isomorphism tests: fix a vertex $x$, and check that there is an automorphism sending $x$ to any other vertex.